# Finding index of a dictionary in a list by key value

Tags: python, python-2.7

How could I find the index of `'node4'` in my dataset a? I want `node4` to be my input for this particular function.

ex:

```
a = [
   {'node1':['node2','node3','node5']},  
   {'node2':['node1','node8','node10']},
   {'node3':['node4','node2']},
   {'node4':['node2','node1','node3']},
   {'node5':['DEADEND']},
   {'node6':['GOAL']}
    ....
    ]
```

Comment: Is this by chance the result of a network flow algorithm?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart it is actually

Comment: Why is this a big list of 1-key dictionaries? One big dictionary might work better, but whatever the program, it's hard to think of a reason you'd build 1-key dicts for this.

Comment: @Liondancer Which library are you using, NetworkX?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart nope i am not

Comment: @user2357112 I want to try your method. How would I convert my list into a dictionary?

Comment: @Liondancer: Well, you'd ideally build it as a dictionary in the first place, but to convert it, you'd do something like `dct = {}; for d in a: dct.update(d)`, except with proper indentation, better variable names, and a line break instead of the semicolon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`next`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next) and [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
>>> next((i for i,x in enumerate(a) if 'node4' in x), None)
3
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def findIndex(inKey):
    for idx, item in enumerate(a):
        if inKey in item:
            return idx
    return None
```

Comment: `if inKey in item` is going to be faster.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Oh, why so? It doesnt have to get the list of keys explicitly?

Comment: @thefourtheye `inkey in item` dictionary key lookup is O(1), while constructing a list/view and  lookup `inKey in item.keys()` is O(N)

Comment: @alko Are you sure `inKey in item` is O(1)? A typical hashtable implementation would calculate the hash O(1), check to see if that bucket is populated O(1), then *iterate* through all items in that bucket O(m), to see if the item being searched for exists. (m is some factor based on hash collision rate and bucket size). Eh, I'm probably just being pedantic.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart yes, I somewhat oversimplified, more details in https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Comment: @alko Average case O(1), worst case O(n). We both win :-)

Answer (score 1):

I would build a dictionary with the indices:

```
>>> index = {key: i for i, elem in enumerate(a) for key in elem}
>>> index['node4']
3
```

This requires going over the entire list once to build the dictionary (which is the worst case  for one-time use anyway) but is then faster if you need it more than once.

Answer (score 1):

Or just like that:

```
    [index for index, record in enumerate(a) if 'node4' in record.keys()][0]
```